# Duplicate columns from MySql db to c#, why?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

[id pojam opis id pojam opis(duplicate columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scN0H.png)
I am just testing connection from db to c#, and instead of columns **id pojam opis** I am actually getting **id pojam opis id pojam opis** in datagridview in c#. Here is part of code which I use to connect database to c#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;database=test;user=root;password=;");

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        ubaciPodatke();        
    }
    public void ubaciPodatke()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM csharp", conn);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(table);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);       
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Is it my mistake, or It has to do something with **phpmyadmin: Version information: 4.7.0-rc1**. I was thinking it can happen because this version isnt stable yet?

**edit**: what do You think if I delete this [form.resx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4G8q.png) 
user added rows, would this solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have manually-defined columns in the `DataGridView`?

Comment: @David good point. I think I only created datagridview from toolbox, but I cant remember if I named columns manually too. that can be it ?

Comment: PS: `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP that aids the maintenance of a **MYSQL** database. The version of `phpMyAdmin` could not be more irrelevant.

Comment: @David columns were not created manually, is there something in dgv that I should turn off?

Comment: @David when I set dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false; I am getting 3 columns but empty dgv, and without autogeneratecolumns I have duplicated columns as I present in question? Where should I place dgv.autogeneratecolumns exactly if that is solution?

Comment: There is no need to do the data binding in the Load event. You can just do it in the constructor after the `InitializeComponent()` call. This is irrelevant to your issue. I don't know what `ubaciPodatke` means since I don't speak that language, but hopefully it is equivalent of `InitializeGrid()`. In that case you should put `dataGridView.DataSource = null; dataGridView.Rows.Clear(); dataGridView.Columns.Clear();` as the first line after `try`

Comment: I do such "clean initialize" since I sometimes design the Grid in designer, for "documentation & visualization" purposes, but do the actual grid from the code

Comment: @Vikhram cool. that works. I know its not related to this question but now, I dont have list anymore pls take a look [link](http://prntscr.com/ej1u43) and [link](http://prntscr.com/ej1uij). Am I reading data from dgv wrong ? thank you!

Comment: @Vikhram I cant vote or anything but your answer is exactly what I needed ! :)

Comment: @Vikhram please post it as the answer, because I think its the best solution to this question I found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few things:**
There is no need to do the data binding in the Load event. You can just do it in the constructor after the `InitializeComponent()` call. This is irrelevant to your issue.

I don't know what `ubaciPodatke` means since I don't speak that language, but hopefully it is equivalent of `InitializeGrid()`. In that case you should put

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView.Columns.Clear();
```

as the first line after try. I do such "clean initialize" since I sometimes design the Grid in designer, for "documentation & visualization" purposes, but do the actual grid from the code. Also, it keeps the `InitializeGrid()` reusable, to be called from other places.

Also, related to the question in the comments,

> Am I reading data from dgv wrong?

You should read the data from the bound `DataTable` and not directly from the  `DataGridView` when binding.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to comment some lines [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQHw.png) in form.designer.cs and problem disappeared as shown in this photo [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lme0Z.png). I am still curious why this happened as I remember only dragging dgv from toolbox and not adding manually column names.